# How to hide <select> dropdown's arrow in Chrome

Tags: php, css, google-chrome

How to hide  dropdown's arrow in Chrome?

on firefox i did it with:

```
-moz-appearance: none;
```

but i don´t know how can i do on Chrome.
Any idea?

thanxs a lot

Answer (score 14):

Use `appearance: none;` and its various prefixed versions to achieve this across different browsers.

```
select {
   -o-appearance: none;
   -ms-appearance: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it eliminates the arrow but also the text of the selectable element....¿?
Try to hide "Ebano Arrow" on [link] (https://www.santullano.com/producto/s03/)

Comment: You have a `display: none !important` on your `select#pa_finish option` selector. This is causing the options to disappear, and is not related to the use of `appearance: none;`.

Comment: I do want the options disappear because of that I have

`select # pa_finish option {
     display: none! important;
}`

but I want the arrows to disappear ... both things

Comment: Then that is the expected outcome. Note that the `select` still shows the default selected value, unless I am missing something. The question was initially to remove the arrows, which my answer provides. Also, avoid linking to external sites. You must provide your cide within the post itself.

Comment: To me your solution does not work. Let's see if I explain ... what I want to achieve (and I still do not get it) 
1-**Hide the options** (for that I use the `select # pa_finish option {display: none! Important;}` (although now I have already removed, not to dismiss in my explanation) 2-**Keep visible the text of the selected option** 3-**Delete the arrows.**

If I use (for Chrome)  `-webkit-appearance: none;` that the only prefix that does something in chrome, it hides the arrows (but not just the arrows): also the text of the default option

Comment: If `option`s are set to `display: none;` it is normal that they don't appear. Although, on Chrome I see it just fine. Firefox seems to require a set height on the `select` (e.g. `height: 20px;`) to make the text reappear, while Safari ignores this altogether. My recommendation is to use the `hidden` attribute on the `option` tags instead of hiding them in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Much like how the prefix `-moz` specifically targets Firefox (and other **[Gecko browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#Gecko-based)**), you're looking for the `-webkit` prefix to target **[WebKit browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based)** like Chrome and Safari.

Hiding **[`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)** dropdowns can be done with **[`-webkit-appearance: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-appearance)**:

```css
select {
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

Note that these vendor prefixes are **unique** to their corresponding browsers, so if you were to apply `-webkit-appearance: none` like above, the dropdowns will be hidden on Chrome, but still visible on Firefox.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it eliminates the arrow but also the text of the selectable element...¿?
Try to hide "Ebano Arrow" on [link] (https://www.santullano.com/producto/s03/)

Comment: @Jose - As you can see with my above example, the text of the selectable element is **not** hidden with `-webkit-appearance-none`. If your text is hidden, you have another rule causing that. However, I'm not going to be clicking on an external link (which may harbour viruses) simply in order to work out what the rule of yours causing this is. If you can highlight the problem in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then by all means, do so, but for now I believe that `-webkit-appearance-none` is all you need.